# How to add the different type of filter in video using the apple core library or using OPEN GL

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mobile

> -:- I have used the GPUImage and other third party library but it's take more time and memory for converting.
>
> -:- I want to apply the diff. type of filter on local stored video.
>
> -:- CIFunHouse is Apple sample code but it's in Objective C, I don't want to use the Bridging-Header.

Your suggestion, sample code, important links are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

> var arrFilterName:NSMutableArray = ["Normal",
>                                           "BoxBlur",
>                                           "ZoomBlur",
>                                           "ToneCurve",
>                                           "Chrome",
>                                           "Fade",
>                                           "Instant",
>                                           "Mono",
>                                           "Process",
>                                           "Tonal",
>                                           "Transfer",
>                                           "ToneCurveToLinear",
>                                           "Vignette",
>                                           "VignetteEffect",
>                                           "SepiaTone"]
>
> var arrFilterLibName:NSMutableArray = ["Normal",
>                                              "CIBoxBlur",
>                                              "CIZoomBlur",
>                                              "CILinearToSRGBToneCurve",
>                                              "CIPhotoEffectChrome",
>                                              "CIPhotoEffectFade",
>                                              "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
>                                              "CIPhotoEffectMono",
>                                              "CIPhotoEffectProcess",
>                                              "CIPhotoEffectTonal",
>                                              "CIPhotoEffectTransfer",
>                                              "CISRGBToneCurveToLinear",
>                                              "CIVignette",
>                                              "CIVignetteEffect",
>                                              "CISepiaTone"]

```
func applyFilter(){
        let str = appDelegate.arr_videourl.objectAtIndex(selectedtag) as! String
        let urlVideo = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: str)
        videoSource = VideoSampleBufferSource(url: urlVideo) { [unowned self] buffer in

            self.image = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer:buffer)

            if self.intIndexx != 0{
                self.currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "\(self.arrFilterLibName[self.intIndexx])")!
                self.currentFilter.setValue(self.image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

                let inputKeys = self.currentFilter.inputKeys

                if inputKeys.contains(kCIInputIntensityKey) { self.currentFilter.setValue(1, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey) }
                if inputKeys.contains(kCIInputRadiusKey) { self.currentFilter.setValue(18, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey) }
                if inputKeys.contains(kCIInputScaleKey)  { self.currentFilter.setValue(0.50, forKey: kCIInputScaleKey) }
                if inputKeys.contains(kCIInputAngleKey)  { self.currentFilter.setValue(0.0, forKey: kCIInputAngleKey) }
                if inputKeys.contains(kCIInputCenterKey) { self.currentFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: 300, y: 300), forKey: kCIInputCenterKey) }

            let processedImage = self.currentFilter.outputImage!

            self.coreImageView?.image = processedImage


        }else{
            self.coreImageView?.image = self.image
        }            
    }
}
```

> - Add the Filter supported file   -CoreImageView.swift   -CameraBufferSource.swift   -VideoSampleBufferSource.swift   -Extensions.swift

Comment: your code produces an output as image i.e processedImage, can you please edit it to result a filtered video instead?